# Find and replace in CudaText editor

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, replace

So I have dump from U-boot and I need to replace specific string in CudaText editor.
Here is mine text

```
e101b1e0: 30ef27d8 e792f415 9beea618 5c601de4    .'.0..........`\
e101b1f0: aeaf9d25 e1dd63e9 536b005b 262a5ef4    %....c..[.kS.^*&
hilinux # 

hilinux # md 0xe100f800 0x3E00

e100f800: 1422b556 4b603659 2ff6c4a4 5e24be15    V.".Y6`K.../..$^
e100f810: bdc025e2 c03d8966 d7120919 dc559b01    .%..f.=.......U.
e100f820: 26f87c02 7d80db89 5c0d3e2a 37712c9d    .|.&...}*>.\.,q7
e10173e0: 2be2a0fa 326d07a9 18cb4b7a 4db0a5ef    ...+..m2zK.....M
e10173f0: ddd7bcec 1fac59f7 17ca6be6 163ee297    .....Y...k....>.
hilinux # 

hilinux # md 0xe100ba00 0x3E00

e100ba00: 33ffc17d 6cda1ed0 a38cfd95 68ffd26d    }..3...l....m..h
e100ba10: 98f71c20 54bf4927 bde58fa8 5782df84     ...'I.T.......W
e100ba20: 789b7a0f feadd17f 07135d9e 48d2fef0    .z.x.....].....H
```

I need delete text bellow

```
hilinux # 

hilinux # md 0xe100f800 0x3E00
(new line is here)
```

the hex number after md is increasing but it is in format 0x00000000.
The expected text should look like this

```
e101b1e0: 30ef27d8 e792f415 9beea618 5c601de4    .'.0..........`\
e101b1f0: aeaf9d25 e1dd63e9 536b005b 262a5ef4    %....c..[.kS.^*&
e100f800: 1422b556 4b603659 2ff6c4a4 5e24be15    V.".Y6`K.../..$^
e100f810: bdc025e2 c03d8966 d7120919 dc559b01    .%..f.=.......U.
e100f820: 26f87c02 7d80db89 5c0d3e2a 37712c9d    .|.&...}*>.\.,q7
e10173e0: 2be2a0fa 326d07a9 18cb4b7a 4db0a5ef    ...+..m2zK.....M
e10173f0: ddd7bcec 1fac59f7 17ca6be6 163ee297    .....Y...k....>.
e100ba00: 33ffc17d 6cda1ed0 a38cfd95 68ffd26d    }..3...l....m..h
e100ba10: 98f71c20 54bf4927 bde58fa8 5782df84     ...'I.T.......W
e100ba20: 789b7a0f feadd17f 07135d9e 48d2fef0    .z.x.....].....H
```

Comment: Do you need to just delete those lines or replace them with blank lines? Edit the question and add the expected result so that this is clear.

Comment: Selecting Replace → regular expression: 1- *Find what*: `^hilinux.*` → *Rep all*. 2- *Find what*: `^$\n` → *Rep all*. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: For orthers: I needed to look up [CudaText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CudaText); it's a Object Pascal-written normal text editor and hex viewer.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity nope it does not work for me

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic Could you elaborate how does not work? I get the expected output you posted.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Oh had turned off "Regular expression" for some reason